# How to avoid copying of a struct when it is a field in another readonly ref struct

Tags: performance, struct, c#-7.2

I have a bunch of extension methods on `Check<T>` defined below. These may be chained together, and some of them *may create new instances* of `Check<T>` (because it is immutable itself, but the `_Success` flag (and other flags not shown below) might need to be changed).

```
public readonly ref struct Check<T> {
  public readonly T Value;
  readonly bool _Success;

  public Check(in T value, bool success = true) {
    Value = value;
    _Success = success;
  }
}
```

What concerns me is the case when `T` is a value type, that is larger than 8 bytes (i.e. a custom struct for example).

Is there a way to avoid copying of `T` instance into `Check<T>`'s `Value` field when creating a new instance of `Check<T>`, and instead have the `Value` field only hold a reference of some sort to the instance of `T`?

After all this `Check<T>` is supposed to be only a wrapper meant to be used only within the stack context.